# Change the name of py.test tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm interested in migrating my test suite from using nose to using py.test. I don't like the test names printed by py.test in the test failure summary, because they don't include the file name of the test. I do really like the test names that py.test uses for to print progress in verbose mode.

For example:

```
[dbw tests]$ py.test -sv r_group/test_meta_analysis/test_meta_analysis.py::_TestPanel::testDisplaySummary
==================================== test session starts ===============================
collected 3 items

r_group/test_meta_analysis/test_meta_analysis.py::_TestPanel::testDisplaySummary FAILED

========================================= FAILURES =====================================
_______________________________ _TestPanel.testDisplaySummary __________________________
```

This is pretty important to me because I have ~40K tests, and the short name "_TestPanel.testDisplaySummary" is not helpful to me in quickly finding the test I want. I assume that there is a built-in py.test hook that will do this, but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`summary_failures()`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/b5dc7d9be1875255cbd58255fa8cf789d36f183a/_pytest/terminal.py#L449) of [`_pytest.terminal.TerminalReporter`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/b5dc7d9be1875255cbd58255fa8cf789d36f183a/_pytest/terminal.py#L95) is the one that prints that line (I found it by searching for the string "FAILURES"). It uses [`_getfailureheadline()`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/b5dc7d9be1875255cbd58255fa8cf789d36f183a/_pytest/terminal.py#L413) to get the test name (and to discard the file name and line number).

I'd suggest subclassing `TerminalReporter` and override `_getfailureheadline()`.

For example:

```
def _getfailureheadline(self, rep):
    if hasattr(rep, 'location'):
        fspath, lineno, domain = rep.location
        return '::'.join((fspath, domain))
    else:
        return super()._getfailureheadline(rep)
```

Produces the following output:

```
test.py::test_x FAILED

================ FAILURES ================
____________ test.py::test_x _____________
```

You can override the default reporter with your own by [writing a new plugin](http://pytest.org/latest/writing_plugins.html) with the following:

```
class MyOwnReporter(TerminalReporter):
    ...

def pytest_configure(config):
    reporter = MyOwnReporter(config, sys.stdout)
    config.pluginmanager.register(reporter, 'terminalreporter')
```

Comment: heh. My conftest.py is loaded before _pytest.terminal, so when _pytest.terminal tries to register, it hits an error. I guess I'll need to pull this into a separate plugin.

Comment: @dbw: yes, I'm suggesting the use of a plugin

Comment: Even in a separate plugin, I still see a traceback when _pytest.terminal tries to register. I'll try to see if there is a way to control registration order.

Comment: @dbw: I tried the code before posting it. The plugin works for me

Comment: Thanks - how did you register the plugin? I was using the pytest_plugins variable in my conftest.py